# I'm having trouble coming up with a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have 2 tables: Media and Galleries. Media contains thousands of records of different types of viral media like videos, pictures, games, etc...Galleries contains a list of gallery id's that are associated with groups of picture records from the media table.

[image: My Tables]

Currently I have a query that will return a list of Gallery records from the Gallery table and associate a MediaThumb from that corresponding group of GalleryIds in the Media table. Here is that query:

```
SELECT a.GalleryID, a.GalleryTitle, a.GalleryDate, MAX(b.MediaThumb) AS MediaThumb
FROM Galleries a
INNER JOIN Media b
ON a.GalleryID = b.GalleryID
GROUP BY a.GalleryID, a.GalleryTitle, a.GalleryDate
order by a.GalleryID desc
```

What I would like to come up with now is a query that returns that list of gallery records along with all records from the Media Table where MediaTypeID = 1 or 2 or 3.

I'm not very good at complex SQL and could use some sort of direction/help. I'm not even sure if what I want is possible. I need the previous query above to be intertwined with the records from the Media table. Hopefully some of you SQL guru's can lend a hand!

Thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want gallery and max thumbnail and associated media row use this:

```
; WITH CTE AS (
SELECT a.GalleryID GalleryID_A, a.GalleryTitle, a.GalleryDate, b.*,  
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  a.GalleryID, a.GalleryTitle, a.GalleryDate 
                    ORDER BY b.MediaThumb DESC) AS Rn
FROM Galleries a
INNER JOIN Media b
ON a.GalleryID = b.GalleryID
Where b.MediaTypeID in (1,2,3)
)
SELECT * FROM CTE where Rn = 1
```

Sample data and results for above query -
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/09e4f/1

Updated Query based on our discussion in chat:

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT a.GalleryID GalleryID_A, a.GalleryTitle, a.GalleryDate, b.*,  
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  a.GalleryID, a.GalleryTitle, a.GalleryDate 
                    ORDER BY b.MediaThumb DESC) AS Rn
FROM Media b
INNER JOIN Gallery A
ON a.GalleryID = b.GalleryID
), 
CTE2 AS
(
SELECT a.GalleryID GalleryID_A, a.GalleryTitle, a.GalleryDate, b.*,  
1 Rn
FROM Media b
LEFT OUTER JOIN Gallery A
ON a.GalleryID = b.GalleryID
)
SELECT * FROm CTE where rn = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM CTE2 WHERE rn = 1 and galleryid is null
order by mediaid
```

fiddle for above- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/72935/12

Comment: I had to discard my answer as you had already posted the CTE :)

Comment: But wouldn't it will give only one record per Gallery... Isn't op  looking at all the records...  Sorry I'm bit confused...  Its been long since I wrote a SQL

Comment: no it will give all records with `max media thumb` value grouped by `a.GalleryID, a.GalleryTitle, a.GalleryDate`

Comment: "What I would like to come up with now is a query that returns that list of gallery records along with all records from the Media Table where MediaTypeID = 1 or 2 or 3." ..  I think op is looking all child records based on MediaTypeID..  He is not concerned about Media Thumb being max...  Atleast that is how I see it.

Comment: Check his last two lines - "I need the previous query above to be intertwined with the records from the Media table."

Comment: @ rs you are correct with what Im looking for. When running your example in SQL Server I get the following error: The column 'GalleryID' was specified multiple times for 'CTE'.

Comment: Updated You have GalleryID in both tables so you need to alias one to different name.

Comment: @rs the second example has the following errors: Invalid column name 'GalleryTitle'. Invalid column name 'GalleryDate'. Those column names dont exist in the media table.

Comment: use first one that should return data you need.

Comment: @rs The first example now executes but returns 0 rows. If i remove the where mediatypeid = section, i get back only the gallery rows similar to the query i provided. The rest of the results are not getting returned.

Comment: @Maddhacker24 Can you check if this returns any count - `select count(*) from media b Where b.MediaTypeID in (1,2,3)`

Comment: @rs yup it returns a count of 5936

Comment: check my sql fiddle link above

Comment: I took a look at the fiddle and updated it slightly to reflect my schema. Have a look: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fc55d/1

Comment: I would expect to get all galleryid records back along with the records that have null for galleryid because those are not part of any gallery.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15774/discussion-between-rs-and-maddhacker24)

Answer (score 0):

You need just use joins without grouping by... Left outer join will ensure all Galleries gets picked up... ie. Gallaries without any corresponding Media also gets picked up.

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM Galleries a
Left outer JOIN Media b ON a.GalleryID = b.GalleryID
Where b.MediaTypeID in (1,2,3)
```